# i want to display the quantity of products user had selected to purchased but 

Tags: php

i had a shopping cart in which there are many products. user can purchase any number of specific item or different items
e.g.
he buys 3 items of product number 1, and
he buys 2 items of product number 2.

This is stored in database as two different records for single user with his id. Now when i want to see totall number of items he has selected.

how can i do that ?

Comment: Very broad question. No one might be able to give a good answer unless you give more information. All I can think of now is, if you are storing something like a shopping cart id then you can just do a select the count of products with a where clause filtering userid and shopping cart id.

Answer (score 1):

You can sum the quantity for each row that user has:

```
SELECT SUM(ItemQuantity) FROM CART WHERE USERID = X
```

Answer (score 1):

with a sql query. look

```
SELECT SUM(items) AS 'total' FROM basket WHERE user_id = ? GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull all the records from the database for that id and purchase date and then combine the relevant columns using some basic maths.